# Java error in mathematical computation

Tags: java, for-loop, computation

I'm trying to print the following series in a table:

```
m(i) = 1/2 + 2/3 + ... + i/(i + 1)
```

The table would look like the one below:

`i   m(i)
 1   0.5000
 2   1.1667
...
 19  16.4023
 20  17.3546`

But the table I'm currently getting is:

`1      0.5
2      0.6666666666666666
3      0.75
4      0.8
5      0.8333333333333334
6      0.8571428571428571
7      0.875
8      0.8888888888888888
9      0.9
10      0.9090909090909091
11      0.9166666666666666
12      0.9230769230769231
13      0.9285714285714286
14      0.9333333333333333
15      0.9375
16      0.9411764705882353
17      0.9444444444444444
18      0.9473684210526315
19      0.95
20      0.9523809523809523`

The code I have so far is below:

```
public class Help {

public static double printSeries(int ch1, int ch2){

    for (int i=ch1; i <= ch2; i++){
        double iPlusOne = i+1;
        double mi =+ i/iPlusOne; 
        System.out.println(i + "      "  + mi);

    }// end of for loop
    return 0.00;
}// end of printSeries method

public static void main(String args[]){
    printSeries(1, 20);
}// end of main method

}// end of class
```

For some reason `mi` isn't adding `mi` to itself. Is there something wrong with the syntax of my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude you declared within the loop itself so on each iteration it's creating a new `mi` variable . Try like this

```
public class Help {

public static double printSeries(int ch1, int ch2){
    double mi=0;
    double iPlusOne=0;
    for (int i=ch1; i <= ch2; i++){
        iPlusOne = i+1;
        mi += i/iPlusOne; 
        System.out.println(i + "      "  + mi);

    }// end of for loop
    return 0.00;
}// end of printSeries method

public static void main(String args[]){
    printSeries(1, 20);
}// end of main method

}// end of class
```

Output :

```
1      0.5
2      1.1666666666666665
3      1.9166666666666665
4      2.716666666666667
5      3.5500000000000003
6      4.4071428571428575
7      5.2821428571428575
8      6.171031746031746
9      7.071031746031746
10      7.980122655122655
11      8.896789321789322
12      9.819866244866246
13      10.748437673437675
14      11.681771006771008
15      12.619271006771008
16      13.560447477359244
17      14.504891921803688
18      15.45226034285632
19      16.40226034285632
20      17.354641295237272
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error. Where you have `=+` should be `+=`. The compiler does not object because it's still a valid statement.